# Formatting powershell output

Tags: powershell

I am running the following PowerShell command, and am looking to only have the result for the C: drive returned. Nothing else.

Command:

```
gwmi win32_volume -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | select driveletter, @{Label="PercentFree";Expression= {"{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace / $_.capacity)}}

Current Output:
driveletter                             PercentFree
-----------                             -----------
                                        41.95 %
C:                                      38.51 %
```

Desired Output:

```
C:                                      38.51 %
```

I can remove columns by say removing the "driveletter" from the command line. But I have no idea how to remove rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the C: drive why not just use a filter for the C:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter 'DriveLetter = "C:"' | select driveletter, @{Label="PercentFree";Expression= {"{0:N0}" -f ($data.freespace / $data.capacity * 100)}}
```

I fixed the percentage logic since a 0. anything should be lost with `:N0`. I only get one return with this.

I think this is cheating but you could also just pipe the output into a `where-Object`

```
... | Where-Object{$_.DriveLetter}
```

**From Comments**

I thought you were wondering where the extra row was coming from. I overlooked you wanted to remove the headers. This would give you want you want

```
 Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter 'DriveLetter = "C:"' | 
     select driveletter, @{Label="PercentFree";Expression= {"{0:N0}" -f ($data.freespace / $data.capacity * 100)}} | 
     Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

Or how about just this then:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter 'DriveLetter = "C:"' | 
    ForEach-Object{"{0} - {1}%" -f $_.driveletter,"{0:N2}" -f ($data.freespace / $data.capacity * 100)}

C: - 49.88%
```

Comment: Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter 'DriveLetter = "C:"' | select driveletter, @{Label="PercentFree";Expression= {"{0:P}" -f ($_.freespace / $_.capacity)}}

Comment: Sorry, the select c: does take care of the blank entry, which is good. But it still has the column labels.

Comment: I run your code and dont get your issue. What is your PS version?

Comment: I am using a windows 8 machine. When I run: get-host|Select-Object version I get: 4.0

Comment: I am looking limit the output to just the row with the data, and not the column headers. So, for instance, I would like to remove "driveletter  PercentFree"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. @user3000911 look at my update

Comment: When I run that, I get: "C:" only. There is no second percentage value.

Comment: You said in your question that you did not want the second percentage. If you are talking about the `Where` just dont use it.

Comment: I was looking for output that looked like "C: 38.51%". At the moment, it returns "C:", and that is it.

Comment: Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter 'DriveLetter = "C:"'| select driveletter, @{Label="PercentFree";Expression= {"{0:P}" -f ($_.freespace / $_.capacity)}}| Format-Table -HideTableHeaders

does work

Comment: Check my last update @user3000911. Just format the output as string!